# AutoFiltering in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use filtering for 4 columns with data. I have problem with .AutoFilter function. Code:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="Crit_1"
```

Is working properly for column P. But when other statement is used like .Range("P:R") instead of .Cells it is working in much different way. I made some tries and I think it is an issue with blank spaces in rows and function is not triggering correctly. As a result all rows goes hidden. Could anyone give me an explanation how exacly this function works? I want to filter 3 columns and check if in 4-th is proper value.

Regards

Comment: `AutoFilter` is sort of tricky to work with multiple criteria.  Will not recommend to use more than two criteria.  Maybe set up a **control** column (`COUNTIFS` or `SUMPRODUCT` can probably achieve your goal) and filter from there.  You can always hide the column for better presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Crit_1" 'For Row P
ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Crit_1" ' For Row Q
ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Crit_1" ' For Row R
```

For the field section, you need to give the value of the column number, so in your case P = 1: Q = 2; R = 3